How to send / download an Outlook image attachment using Power Automate
How to download an Outlook image attachment using Power Automate:

I am trying to download an image using Power Automate, but it gives me data instead of an image in the email body.
"attachments": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
      "id": "AAMkADU2MjNiNTU2LWY5YTAtNGM0MS1hNWQ5LTdmMTJlMTIzYWJkMQBGAAAAAABfK4moQ22ISJuBMsoGIcM6BwAAywrHK3zOT5jkS4DyLB8BAAHpvk0cAAAAywrHK3zOT5jkS4DyLB8BAAHpvl0DAAABEgAQAPen6EKm26ZJhIAv3bw2opc=",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-24T09:35:06+00:00",
      "name": "2ff5730931074c29be64df06c8126e97",
      "contentType": "image/png",
      "size": 204114,
      "isInline": true
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
      "id": "AAMkADU2MjNiNTU2LWY5YTAtNGM0MS1hNWQ5LTdmMTJlMTIzYWJkMQBGAAAAAABfK4moQ22ISJuBMsoGIcM6BwAAywrHK3zOT5jkS4DyLB8BAAHpvk0cAAAAywrHK3zOT5jkS4DyLB8BAAHpvl0DAAABEgAQANRa3svAlylEn6SII-zNjQk=",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-24T09:35:06+00:00",
      "name": "WeeklyAuditReport - (Page 1).png",
      "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
      "size": 240586,
      "isInline": false
    }
  ]
} 

That is the output generated by Power Automate.
How can I send this attachment in my Outlook email as an image, not in JSON format, using Power Automate? Please provide an answer as soon as possible without requiring any Power Automate subscription. I have visited multiple websites, but none have given me a correct answer.

Please give me an answer.

Show us your flow. What operations are you using?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#get-attachment-(v2)

@skin Hello
I am using the get_attachment(v2) function, but it returns a JSON format as shown in the attached code not image.

What's your trigger?

@skin
I have used two components  "when a new email arrives(V3)  and Get_attachment(V2)"

Do you get contentBytes back from the get attachment call?

Hello @skin , yes but it returns a JSON format as shown in the attached code not image

Hello @Skin, I am clear about my entire requirement. Have you seen the 'subscribe to report' email from Power BI? My requirement is to extract the image from that Power BI 'subscribe to report' email, retrieve the email attachment from an Outlook email, and then send it to another person.

I’m not sure what you expect, you won’t get an image, you’ll get an encoded version of it. That’s exactly what it gives you. You should then turn that into HTML for the email. Why not just forward the email you get by using a rule or something? Sounds easier to me.
